# Out of source builds in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, autotools, out-of-source

Is this possible to compile a project out of its source directory using eclipse/autotools? I need to keep source tree clean.

What I already tried:

Changing directory at: `Project properties -> C/C++ builds -> Build directory`. (Default value is `${workspace_loc:/project-name}/`.) Though this didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing might be to treat your build like a CMake-style project, with source and build directories: https://cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator

Essentially, you have 2 Eclipse projects, one for source, and one for the build.  Simply link to the source directory from the build directory.  You can have your build targets in the build project, and navigation and version control will work in the source project.